High GPU memory usage with onnx model in tensorrt8
I have a code like this.
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import tensorrt as trt
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import zipfile
import io
import os
TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.WARNING)
model_file = "models.onnx"
key = "key"

def load_model(fname):
    if fname.endswith(".uff"):
        return fname
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        model = f.read()
    return model

def load_compressed_model(fname, key, temp):
    fernet = Fernet(key)
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        content = fernet.decrypt(f.read())

    with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(content)) as zf:
        models = [n for n in zf.namelist()]
        assert len(models) == 1
        temp.write(zf.read(models[0]))
        temp.flush()
        return load_model(temp.name)

def build_engine(input_names, model):
    def gib(val):
        return val * 1 << 30
    EXPLICIT_BATCH = 1 << (int)(trt.NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag.EXPLICIT_BATCH)
    builder = trt.Builder(TRT_LOGGER)
    builder_config = builder.create_builder_config()
    builder_config.max_workspace_size = int(gib(1) * 0.15)
    builder_config.flags = trt.BuilderFlag.FP16
    builder.max_batch_size = 1
    print(EXPLICIT_BATCH)
    network = builder.create_network(EXPLICIT_BATCH)
    parser = trt.OnnxParser(network, TRT_LOGGER)
    parser.parse(model)
    return builder.build_engine(network, builder_config)


from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=os.path.splitext(model_file)[-1]) as temp:
    model = load_model(model_file) if 'raw_models' in model_file \
        else load_compressed_model(model_file, key, temp)
    engine = build_engine(model_file, model)

When I use nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:20.09-py3, it works good for me, gpu memory usage is about 400MB.
Version info:
nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0

env | grep "CUDNN"
CUDNN_VERSION=8.0.4.12

>>> import tensorrt
>>> tensorrt.__version__
'7.1.2.8'

But when I update the image nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:22.12-py3, when running on builder.build_engine(***) it use about 6000M gpu memory.
Version info:
nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0

env | grep "CUDNN"
CUDNN_VERSION=8.7.0.84

>>> import tensorrt
>>> tensorrt.__version__
'8.5.1.7'

NVIDIA driver version is 550.78.
I'm sure that I'm using the same model. But I don't know why the gpu memory usage is so high. What can I do for this issue？
I have no idea for this issue and just adjust builder_config.max_workspace_size smaller, but it does not work.
I wonder to know what happened in tensorrt cause this issue and how can I reduce the memory usage.
